# Git commit commands

Tags: git

In my Git repo, I changed some files. I want to stage all of them. But is there a difference between commands:

```
git add file1.php file2.php

git add .
```

Does the second command stage only modified files, or all files from project? Or these commands are equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git add file1.php file2.php` stages the files `file1.php` and `file2.php`.

`git add .` stages all files in the directory and all subdirectories, including uncommitted ones. (As long as they're not ignored by your `.gitignore`)

Either command will only stage a file if it's been modified, however.

Comment: Your last sentence is a little misleading. It's more accurate to say that staging an unmodified file is a no-op: the staging area already implicitly contains the unmodified version. Further, both commands will also stage *new* files.

Comment: @Jefromi, true, if you think of the index as storing the full tree of the next commit, rather than just the *difference* between the HEAD and the next commit. Which is the correct way to think of it, of course, but that might not be obvious to a git newcomer.

Answer (score 1):

If `file1.php` and `file2.php` are the only files that have changed or are untracked the two commands are equivalent, because unchanged files can't be staged anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Sebastian P., these commands are not equavalent.

To stage all modified files, you can use `git add -u`

Also, for a quick commit of all modified files, you can use `git commit -a` which is equivalent to `git add -u ; git commmit`